# What API limits are imposed on Knowledge Base REST API?

Tags: api, rest, knowledge

I would like to know what limitations are there on the Knowledge Base REST API?

Would this use the same API limits imposed in a Salesforce org? or does it also use the Site.com limits (number of page loads etc)

Comment: All the usual limits apply. Just because an API might be used via a Community or a Site doesn't remove the API call limits.

Comment: Please formulate to an answer.